# Compare two hashmaps by keys and return keys which do not have same frequencies

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I would like to sort two HashMaps by keys and compare their values and print out all the keys which do not have same value. Could you help me how to do this. Here is my code as below. I am new to Java and learning data structures one by one. Thanks for the help.

**Code :-**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int val;

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> h1 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for( int i=0;i<n;i++ ) {           
             val = scan.nextInt();
             if(!h1.containsKey(val)) {
                 h1.put(val,1);
             }
            else {
                h1.put(val,h1.get(val)+1);
            }
         }

        int m = scan.nextInt();

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> h2 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

         for( int i=0;i<m;i++ ) {           
             val = scan.nextInt();
             if(!h2.containsKey(val)) {
                 h2.put(val,1);
             }
            else {
                h2.put(val,h2.get(val)+1);
            }
         }

        System.out.println(h1.keySet());   
        System.out.println(h1.values());
        System.out.println(h2.keySet());   
        System.out.println(h2.values());

        }           
}
```

Comment: What does sorting have to do with it?

Comment: Guava's `Maps.difference()` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sort your hash maps in order to produce your desired output. Instead, construct a `TreeSet<Integer>` containing the union of keys from both maps, like this

```
SortedSet<Integer> allKeysSorted = new TreeSet<Integer>();
allKeysSorted.addAll(h1.keySet());
allKeysSorted.addAll(h2.keySet());
```

Using `TreeSet` ensures that your keys are sorted. Now you can iterate `allKeysSorted`, get the corresponding value from each map, and compare accordingly:

```
for (Integer key : allKeysSorted) {
    int v1, v2;
    if (h1.containsKey(key)) {
        v1 = h1.get(key);
    } else {
        v1 = 0;
    }
    if (h2.containsKey(key)) {
        v2 = h2.get(key);
    } else {
        v2 = 0;
    }
    ... // Compare v1 and v2 here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should allow you to sort the maps.

```
SortedSet<Integer> values1 = new TreeSet<Integer>(h1.keySet());
SortedSet<Integer> values2 = new TreeSet<Integer>(h2.keySet());
```

Should return a set with the unique values of the two sets.

```
    Set<Integer> result = new SortedSet<Integer>(values1);  
    for (Integer element : values2) {
        if (!h1.containsValue(h2.get(element)) {  //If they don't share same value, add it to this new Set
            result.add(element);
        }
        result.remove(element);  //If they both share same value, remove it
    }
```

Finally, to print:

```
Iterator iter = result.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to merge `h1` and `h2` entries by subtracting their values into a new `TreeMap`, which sorts entries by key. Then, we could remove the entries with values equal to zero:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> merged = new TreeMap<>(h1); // Copy h1 into merged

h2.forEach((k2, v2) -> merged.merge(k2, v2, (oldVal, newVal) -> oldVal - newVal));

merged.values().removeIf(v -> v.equals(0));
```

To print the keys, you could simply print the map's keyset:

```
System.out.println(merged.keySet());
```

Or iterate its keys and print them one by one:

```
merged.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```